# select a description from a static row based on the results of a formula in each row

Tags: excel, macos, cell

I am trying to create a formula to apply a description to each row in a table based on a formula in each row.

***Example of table:***
[image]

I want to enter a category description in column G based on the first non zero entry in each row
e.g. in row 3 the result would be B; in row 4, the result would C and in row 9 the result would be E.

My problem is developing a formula for column H in each row which will produce those results.

Can anyone help?

Therein lies the problem, the Lookup functions don't apply since i can't identify, by formula, the first non zero cell in each row

Comment: Please put the sample data in table markdown format, you can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) copy the data from your  excel, generate the table and copy into your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `BYROW()` with `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=BYROW(B3:F9,LAMBDA(x,TAKE(FILTER(B2:F2,x>0),1,1)))
```

`XLOOKUP()` should also work.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,B3:F3,$B$2:$F$2,,1)
```

[image]